# WaitForSingleObject Does Not Time Out - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, timeout, winapi

My console application calls `WaitForSingleObject` in the parent thread with a timeout value of 5 seconds.

```
dwObjectWaitState = ::WaitForSingleObject( s_hRxDataEvent, 50000L );
```

After configuring the physical environment (i.e. no code changes), so that the event will never get signaled, I set a breakpoint at the following line, and run the application.  The PC never gets to the breakpoint.  `s_hRxDataEvent` is a valid event handle that is normally set in a child thread.  The application works great when the physical environment is configured as expected.  Why doesn't the function time out?  Thanks.

Comment: Your value there is 50 seconds, did you wait 50 seconds? 5 seconds would be `5000L`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout is in milliseconds. 50000 is 50 seconds, not 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have an extra zero there.

Answer (score 1):

50000L milliseconds = 50 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The timeout value for [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202783.aspx) is specified in milliseconds, so 50000L means 50 seconds, not 5 seconds.